# Can you please tell me why I am getting ths error custom class tailwindcss error

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, vite

This is my vite-react project where I am using tailwindcss and I am getting this error saying

[Browser result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xP8e8.png)

[Inside Vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwtMc.png)

I have already installed tailwind css and `bg-dark-1` is a custom class and is already inside @layer directive but not sure why I am getting error.

If I remove
`body { @apply bg-dark-1 text-white min-h-screen font-inter; }` 
the project is working fine.

Can you tell me how to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

apply it as you would in a css file

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

body { @apply bg-dark-1 text-white min-h-screen font-inter; }
```